# Apply a function to each row of data.table, optimal approach

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I have some curves defined like this

```
library(data.table)
basesheet <- data.table(
  ID_CURVE = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), 
  TIME = rep(seq(1:3),2), 
  value = c(rep(0.1,3),rep(0.2,3)),
  extrapolate=rep(c(0,2.5,6),2))
```

my problem is to extrapolate for the points defined by TIMExvalue the linear approximation at the time point "extrapolate".

I was thinking about getting the data into this structure

```
aaa <- basesheet[,
  .(TIMES = list(c(TIME)), VALUESTR = list(c(value)), EXTRA = list(c(extrapolate)))
, by =ID_CURVE]
```

which gives

```
ID_CURVE TIMES    VALUESTR       EXTRA
1:        a 1,2,3 0.1,0.1,0.1 0.0,2.5,6.0
2:        b 1,2,3 0.2,0.2,0.2 0.0,2.5,6.0
```

and then apply approx function to each row to recieve the result, something like

```
aaa[, value := mapply(approx, TIMES, y=VALUESTR, EXTRA, method = linear",
                  rule = 2)]
```

but I cannot figure out how to do things properly, can anyone suggest a solution or better approach?

Comment: Fyi, `c(x)` is rarely useful. Typically, it's only used with multiple arguments to combine them `c(x,y)`. You can do `basesheet[, c(lapply(.SD, list), .(fit = .(approx(TIME, y=value, extrapolate, method="linear", rule=2)$y))), by=ID_CURVE]`, but I think it's cleaner as `basesheet[, fit := approx(TIME, y=value, extrapolate, method="linear", rule=2)$y, by=ID_CURVE]` (not sure if either piece of code is giving the right result, though, since you did not show expected output).

Comment: ok thank you very much, I have used your solution. I really appreciate your help. Jakub